# Generate a count of sales that exceed a limit in MS Access - Design View

Tags: ms-access

I am needing to determine a count of sales that exceeded a limit.

I have a table called Limits and it lists the value limits by organization type.  Each organization has a Contact that is responsible for not going over this set limit based on their organization type.  I have a table of 2015 sales including the price for each sale.

I have to produce a field that essentially counts the number of sales that exceed the set limit for their organization.

I am an amature with Access and I have to do all this in Design Mode, not SQL.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  I figure I have to compare the price of each sale to the limit set but I am lost on how to set that up in the field boxes.  I have tried different expressions and functions but I am not getting the right result.

[image: Initial Setup]

Comment: As far as I can tell, tables do not have any relationship that will allow linking to pull appropriate limit. Makes no sense to link on Price and Limit fields. Sales table needs a link to Organization then limit is pulled via linking Organization to Limits. I don't see anything in Sales that will associate with Organization.

Comment: Should not have separate tables for each year.

Comment: Saying the same thing in different words: browsing the 2015 sales data, how can you tell how to connect a sale record to an organization?  There is nothing there that obviously tells us an organization.